# Как вставить число после подпоследовательности?

Tags: c++

Написал программу, которая раскладывает по порядку числа из файла.

Но нужно, чтобы после первой подпоследовательности (состоящей из нечетных чисел) вставляло число 0.

Подскажите как это сделать (написать)?

код:

```
#include <fstream>
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TList list;
    ifstream file ("input.txt");

    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "File not found!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        Create_Order(list, file);
        Print(list);
        Clear(list);
        file.close();
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Header.h

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream> 

struct Node 
{
    int info;
    Node* next; 
};

typedef Node* TList;

void Init(TList& list);

bool Empty(TList list);

void Add(TList& list, int new_elem);

int Delete(TList& list);

void Create_Order(TList& list, std::ifstream& file);

void Print(TList list);

void Clear(TList& list);
```

Header.cpp

```
void Init(TList& list)
{
    list = NULL;
}

bool Empty(TList list)
{
    return list == NULL;
}

void Add(TList& list, int new_elem)
{
    TList p = new Node;
    p->info = new_elem;
    p->next = list;
    list = p;
}

int Delete(TList& list)
{
    TList p = list;
    list = p->next;
    int elem = p->info;
    p->next = NULL;
    delete p;
    return elem;
}

TList Found_place(TList list, int elem)
{
    TList Q = list;
    while (Q->next != NULL && Q->next->info < elem)
        Q = Q->next;
    return Q;
}

void Create_Order(TList& list, std::ifstream& file)
{
    Init(list);
    int x;
    file >> x;
    Add(list, x); // или Add_to_head(list, x)

    while (!file.eof())
    {
        file >> x;
        if (x < list->info)
            Add(list, x); // или Add_to_head(list, x)
        else
        {
            TList place = Found_place(list, x);
            Add(place->next, x);//или Add_after_Node(place,x)
        }
    }
} 

void Print(TList list)
{
    TList p = list;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << p->info << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void Clear(TList& list)
{
    while (!Empty(list))
        Delete(list); // или Delete_from_head(list)
}
```

Comment: "_после подпоследовательностей_" - это как?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Задайте вопрос формализованно, ясно и недвусмысленно...

Comment: И учтите, что здесь скриншоты очень не любят. Есть же текст, скопируйте - Ctrl-C-Ctrl-V - неужели это труднее, чем картинки делать?

Comment: Выложите код текстом,  а не картинкой. Я не верю, что вам проще было заскринить код, чем скопировать и вставить

Comment: Выложите полный код. Например как у вас выглядит функция `Create_Order`?

Comment: подпоследовательность - 3 4 5 6 , т.е по порядку идущие несколько цифр из списка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример функции `Add_Zero`, которая вставляет `0` после первой подпоследовательности нечетных чисел.

Сразу скажу протестируйте пожалуйста по максимуму, т.к. у меня нет возможности протестировать у себя, но вроде должно работать :)

```
void Add_Zero(TList& list) {
    TList Q = list;
    //Пропускаем сначала четные
    while (Q->next != NULL && Q->info % 2 == 0)
        Q = Q->next;

    //true - если не конец списка, то есть началась нечетная подпоследовательность
    bool isSubsequense = Q->info % 2 == 1;
    //Указатель на последний элемент подпоследовательности
    TList last = Q;
    //Потом идем в конец первой нечетной подпоследовательности
    while (Q->next != NULL && Q->next->info % 2 == 1) {
        Q = Q->next;
        last = Q;
    }

    //Если подпоследовательность есть
    if (isSubsequense) {
        TList newElem = new Node;
        newElem->info = 0;
        //Если последний элемент этой подпоследовательности
        //находится в конце списка, то просто добавить в конец 0
        if (last->next == NULL) {
            newElem->next = NULL;
            last->next = newElem;
        }
        //Иначе вставляем между элементам
        else {
            Q = last->next;
            last->next = newElem;
            newElem->next = Q;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это код для Header.cpp файла ?

Comment: @Алекс это функция, которую можете написать и в `Header.cpp` а её прототип в `Header.h`, и если я вам помог то выберите ответ как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)